# how to set default route in vuejs with multiple pages

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using vue cli and implemented a multiple page application in `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    bla: {
      entry: 'src/pages/bla/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      title: 'blaaaaa',
    },
    foo: {
      entry: 'src/pages/foo/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      title: 'foooooo',
    }
  }
}
```

In `/router/index.js`:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
  { path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*', name: 'NotFound', component: NotFoundView.vue },
  { path: '/', redirect: '/bla' },
  { path: '/bla', name: 'Bla', component: () => import('@/views/bla/BlaView.vue') },
  { path: '/foo', name: 'FooView', component: () => import('@/views/foo/MoiView.vue') },
  { path: '/foo/bar', name: 'FooBarView', component: () => import('@/views/foo/FooBarView.vue') },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

All this works fine, but I don't see how to add a default route for root, although the documentation on  [Redirect and Alias](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html) seems clear. Going to '/' should redirect to '/bla' but vue isn't even detected on the page. Same problem with the NotFound page I tried: vue is not found.

Comment: You can literally add a route for root that redirects to where you want. Check the documentation for syntax

Comment: I had read the documentation and updated my post accordingly.